# MongoDB: MapReduce or Aggregation in a master/slave configuration

Tags: mongodb, mapreduce, aggregation-framework

I am working on the application which understands customer behavior by tracking the user activities using events and pushing them to mongodb.

Now I want to derive the information out of it like % drop at a particular page or the number of users who purchased a product.. so on & so forth.

I went through the topic here on MR vs Aggregation in MongoDB and learnt that MR is not fast enough as compared to aggregation( may be in a non sharded environment).

1. Is sharded/non sharded setup of mnogo the only reason for choosing MR vs aggregation or vice versa?
2. Is MR the strong contender in the situation mentioned above?

Comment: Both MapReduce and Aggregation work on sharded cluster. The former is more flexible, but slower. The rule of thumb is if you can do it with aggregation, use it.

Comment: Okay. Thanks Alex.

Comment: Another bit is, I want to read those events generated from step one, and follow & understand the pattern to decide on certain parameters. I think I should go ahead with MapReduce. What do you think?

Comment: I think you are asking wrong questions. It is too broad, and is not quite clear what's the problem.